# How to get a date from sqlite used on android app

Tags: android, string, sqlite, date

```
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/assets.db", null);
    Cursor c=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select datetime('now')", null);       
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
            tv.setText(c.getString(0));
    }
    tv.setText("1234");
    c.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

I have wrote this code to operate an `SQLite` database to get the current date and show the date in a textView. When i run the code, it shows no error, but the final result shown that the sql state `select datetime('now')` didn't return a current date. The textView shown "1234" but not the date.

please tell me what's wrong with the code or if this methods is a wrong method.
p.s i know how to get the date by using java calendar, this question is only asked for whether can i get the date directly by querying the SQLite database.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
if(c.getCount() >0)

  c.moveToFirst();

  tv.setText(c.getString(0));

 }
 else{
     tv.setText("1234"); 
  }
    c.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

put last  `tv.setText` inside else .

Answer (score 0):

Is it a joke? After setting the date in the textview, you rewrite in the textview 1234. It's normal to not see the date.

Comment: oh my god!!
i'm so sorry about asking stupid question.
it takes me half night...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have else expression after if, this is your problem.

try this:

```
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try{ 
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list or get object
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tv.setText(c.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else{
                tv.setText("1234");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
    finally{
        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
        if(!db.equals(null) || db != null)
            db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with date try the followings

Date filed in the SQLite table will be TEXT and date data should be stored as "2012-12-31 00:12:00" format that comparison dose not give you trouble and if we consider that fields are date_from and date_to and we are storing current date at to_date then we should get the current date as bellow and

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String to_date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

and the SQL query should be

```
crs = db.rawQuery(
  "SELECT _id, date_from, date_to, done_or_not, list_name " +
  "FROM list_tbl " +
  "WHERE " +
  "date_from <= Datetime('"+to_date+"') AND date_to >= Datetime('"+to_date+"')", null);
```